# passwordToggleEnabled doesn't seem to be working

Tags: android, android-edittext, passwords, android-support-library, android-textinputlayout

I have implemented a TextInputLayout with a password field in the usual way:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:autofillHints="password"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#9e9e9e" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I have added this in the dependencies -

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

The visibility "eye- icon" is not yet visible. Is there anything that I missed or I did do sommething wrong?

Comment: Use `app:endIconMode="password_toggle"` on the TextInputLayout instead of `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"`.

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks but this doesn't seem to be working for me!

Comment: @TanyaAgrawal Post also your app theme. Also using an `EditText` instead of `TextInputEditText` make sure to set its `android:background` to `@null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to use a [Material Components theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes) in your app and use a layout like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    android:hint="@string/password"
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        ...
        android:inputType="textPassword"
    />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

As you are using an `EditText` please check [the official doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextField.md#using-text-fields):

> **Note:** A text field is composed of a `TextInputLayout` and a `TextInputEditText` as a direct child. Using an `EditText` as the child **might work**, but `TextInputEditText` provides accessibility support for the text field and allows `TextInputLayout` greater control over the visual aspects of the input text. **If an `EditText` is being used, make sure to set its `android:background` to `@null`** so that `TextInputLayout` can set the proper background on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/pass"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```